# Synthesis-able 'X' or invalid input detection system in Verilog

Tags: verilog, synthesis

I am trying to make a synthesis-able Verilog code, which can detect 'x' or invalid inputs. Basically, `x` is not synthesis-able so I am avoiding `x`. I am trying to read inputs at every clock cycles and if it is `0` or `1` then I am loading into a new register. Here is the code;

```
always@(posedge clk)
begin
    if(in & gate_check == 0 | in & gate_check == 1)
    begin
        load_input_8 <= {in,load_input_8[8:1]}; 
    end
end
```

So, I am loading new inputs into `load_input_8` register, after checking validity of input data. By the way, `gate_check` has value of 1 i.e. `gate_check = 1.

But this is only storing value of `1` into `load_input_8`. No `0` is being stored in `load_input_8`. And circuit is also having strange behavior in loading inputs. Here is the picture of simulation;
[image]
Thank you.

Comment: Only `in = 1` can satisfy your if condition.

Comment: @Laleh, Thank you. Problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Laleh for helping in this issue. There was issues of `()`. Here is correct code;

```
always@(posedge clk)
begin
    if((in & gate_check) == 0 | (in & gate_check) == 1)
    begin
        load_input_8 <= {in,load_input_8[8:1]}; 
    end
end
```